# Finding the Particular digit of Pi using TakeWhile

Tags: list-manipulation

```
TakeWhile[First[RealDigits[Pi, 10, 100]], # != 7 &]
```

This is used to calculate the first occurrence of 7 but how to get the 20th occurrence of 7.

Answer (score 3):

In three steps so that it is easier to understand what's going on:

```
First[RealDigits[Pi, 10, 1000]] // Short
Position[%, 7][[20, 1]]
%%[[1 ;; % - 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### *... using  `TakeWhile`:*

```
ClearAll[digitsUpToMthK]
digitsUpToMthK[mth_, k_, n_] := Module[{t = 0}, 
  TakeWhile[First[RealDigits[Pi, 10, n]], Or[# != k, (++t) < mth] &]]
```

Examples:

```
digitsUpToMthK[3, 7, 10000]
```

> {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6,  4, 3, 3, 8, 3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 0, 2, 8, 8, 4, 1, 9}

```
Length @ digitsUpToMthK[20, 7, 1000]
```

> 301

```
Short @ digitsUpToMthK[20, 7, 1000]
```

> {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2, 3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6,  4, 3, 3, 8, 3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 0, 2, 8, 8,
>   << 230 >>,
>    4, 8, 6, 1, 0, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 6, 4, 8, 2, 1, 3, 3, 9,  3, 6, 0, 7, 2, 6, 0, 2, 4, 9, 1, 4, 1, 2, 7, 3}

If you need the position of  $m$th occurence of a given digit, you can use `LengthWhile`:

```
ClearAll[posOfMthK]
posOfMthK[mth_, k_, n_] := Module[{t = 0}, 
  1 + LengthWhile[First[RealDigits[Pi, 10, n]], Or[# != k, (++t) < mth] &]]
```

Examples:

```
posOfMthK[20, 7, 100000]
```

> 302

```
posOfMthK[100, 3, 100000]
```

> 937